# How to put data from a register into a buffer in assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

So I'm trying to write an assembly program that displays the hex address of the command line arguments followed by the command line argument itself eg

```
0x01234567: command line argument 1
```

I've loaded the address of the string into a register, and I'm trying to put it into a buffer to convert it from hex to text so it displays properly in the terminal.

If I do the following to load the address of the first string into ebx,

```
lea ebx,[ArgPtrs+edi*4]
```

is there a way to move that value into a buffer?

Comment: I think what you want to do is push the value onto the stack and then call `printf`. Btw, are you using assembly on Windows or Linux?

Comment: through linux. im trying to avoid c right now and do it in pure assembly.

Comment: Then I think you want to allocate some bytes of memory on the stack, do the number-to-hex-string conversion, then do the system call named `write()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, it was just some assembly growing pains and poor syntax.

What I had initially was this-

```
lea ebx,[ArgPtrs+edi*4]
mov [AddrBuff+edi*4],ebx
```

Just needed to add on the dword to the mov instruction to make it a legal instruction..

```
mov dword [AddrBuff+edi*4],ebx
```